# Would more options of the death penalty be believable to present day audience and setting?

Tags: super-powers, law, alternate-earth, death, law-enforcement

In one of my stories, my MC is a spy and has an ability to come back from the dead (but can't reveal such a fact) and after her first murder (she got killed by a mole and had her arm cut off with an axe) her killer used her DNA, fingerprints (from removed hand) to set her up for the deaths of 4 other agents (killed by bullets).

After waking up from her death, she's disorientated but gets recovered by people who have abilities as well (such as teleportation). However, she wants to clear her name. But for the safety of her powered friends, she can't reveal them or her own unique nature to anyone. Including to the government.

The US government is very similar to the present day in terms of technology and law. But, ultimately, the MC is found out and arrested for the crimes they were framed for. A few of the families push for the death penalty and the judge and jury are rigged against her (it's set up by a mole fraction that the MC is aware of inside the government) but it's presented to be genuine and legal for appearances to public and victim's families.

So ultimately, she's sentenced to death. She defensive-arguments have weaknesses, such as the time frame of healing of her arm (a healing power helped there) and how they ended up a few hundred miles away from the crime scene 'without' transport. The murders took place in cold, Canadian wilderness, in a sort of secret base (if she hadn't died in the attack, she would have frozen to death before getting anywhere even if she tried), so it's ruled to a belief she took normal transport for the time gap, which made it look like she was lying if she came up with something else as all other equipment was accounted for.

Gifted/powered people aren't too common for the general public, even less for their trials, there are some but her unique abilities couldn't conventionally be tested if she admitted them. Most would not believe her as resurrection is considered an unlikely ability in comparison to those gifted that are registered. Some might see this as her 'attempting' to intimidate or upset the ruling by claiming it wasn't actually possible to kill her.

Now, with her sentenced to die, there are options to our current world-standards.

Lethal injection is far the most commonly practised and there are back up methods such as gas or the electric chair.

But for me, I feel that with this alternate-earth, and bigger crime rates and unusual abilities, there would be more options of capital punishments available (including the two above) such as Hanging, Firing squad, suffocation (similar to gas-death), poisoning and decapitation.

The punishment is sentenced in the USA.

But I want to know if the alternative options are available for my MC to be able to choose from (they do have a fear of needles so they're not fond of the idea of lethal injection) and if they are, **would any of those options be something that could be legally acceptable enough that it's believable for the readers?**

Comment: Relevant E.E. Doc Smith quote from 1939: "*Therefore, as long as she stays alive--or even not dead, the way she is now--guard her so heavily that an army can't get her. If she should happen to die, don't leave her body unguarded for a second until she's been autopsied and you know she'll stay dead.*"

Comment: How does "gifted/powered people aren't too common... even less for their trials, ... her unique abilities couldn't conventionally be tested if she admitted them" jibe with the idea of bigger executions for supers? It sounds like the idea of these powers is still pretty new and doesn't have much official recognition, so I would assume their law cleaves pretty closely to our own.

Comment: Just as a general sidenote, just because the USA has capital punishment, does not mean that those on death row are actually executed a couple days after the gavel falls in the courtroom. Death row frequently has a backlog of years, and it's not uncommon for people to die of old age before execution.

Comment: Most people don't actually object to the method. They object because either (a) capital punishment is immoral/inhumane/etc. or (b) it's not an effective deterrent. Therefore, more methods don't solve your problem. You need to convince people that it's *right and acceptable.* After you've done that, you could all but torture them to death using any method you want and no one would care.  (BTW, Some note that CP isn't a deterrent, it's to remove someone who's too expensive to keep around but can't ever be trusted in society. See the problem? What's "too expensive?")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Constitution prohibits cruel executions

The Eighth Amendment to the US Constitution prohibits torture: "Excessive bail shall not be required, nor excessive fines imposed, **nor cruel and unusual punishments inflicted.**"

The courts are not fans of spectacle executions, and for good reason.  In 1972's [Furman v. Georgia](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1971/69-5030), the Supreme Court temporarily ended the death penalty, writing, "the Eighth and Fourteenth Amendments cannot tolerate the infliction of a sentence of death under legal systems that permit this unique penalty to be so wantonly and so freakishly imposed."

Obviously executions are now allowed. Some methods have been explicitly approved. [Electrocution](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/136/436/) was long ago permitted by the Supreme Court. In [Baze v. Rees](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/07pdf/07-5439.pdf), the Supreme Court approved the three-drug lethal injection method used most frequently today.

So what are the borders to legality? According to [Helling v. McKinney](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1992/91-1958) (and affirmed in Baze), an execution method cannot be used if it is "sure or very likely to cause serious illness and needless suffering." [Wilkerson](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/99/130) lists old English punishments like hanging drawing and quartering and burning at the stake, and says that they are forbidden by the Eighth Amendment, though the opinion says that the boundaries are sometimes tricky to set:

> Difficulty would attend the effort to define with exactness the
> extent of the constitutional provision which provides that cruel and
> unusual punishments shall not be inflicted; but it is safe to affirm
> that punishments of torture, such as those mentioned [above], and all
> others in the same line of unnecessary cruelty, are forbidden by that
> [a]mendment to the Constitution.

So let's review what we know about the methods that you list in your question and in the answers:

- **Suffocation**. You mention the possibility of using suffocation. Baze explicitly prohibits any form of execution that carries "a substantial, constitutionally unacceptable risk of suffocation." So that's out.
- **Poisoning**. How would this work? The details really matter here. Baze makes it clear that you'd have to have a way of killing the person without causing pain. Baze mentions the possibility of a single-drug lethal injection (which is arguably a form of poisoning) but the Court declined to offer an opinion.
- **Firing squad.** The firing squad is a legal form of execution per the [Supreme Court](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/99/130). The court noted that soldiers have been subject to execution by firing squad for a very long time.
- **Decapitation**. Nope. Wilkerson explicitly lists "beheading" as one of the old English methods of execution that are not allowed in the United States.
- **Hanging**. Probably allowed. This is [still on the books](https://deathpenaltyinfo.org/executions/methods-of-execution) as a method of execution in some states, but its Constitutionality has not been challenged since Baze. The last time it was reviewed, a [split decision from the 9th Circuit](https://casetext.com/case/campbell-v-wood-3) approved of its use.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a more fascistic, militaristic government (it sounds like you might), there's no reason that any number of inhumane sentences wouldn't be viewed as believable.

[Firing squad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_the_United_States#Methods) is still available in the US *right now*, so there's no reason that wouldn't believable.  Hanging and decapitation both have histories of botched executions being incredibly grisly, so unless the powers that be *want* that kind of public spectacle, it's unlikely they'd continue either.

It's also worth noting that if US law is similar to today, she would expect to wait fifteen years (or more) on Death Row for her execution.  If the trial is public enough that the families of those killed are calling publicly for her execution, then it seems unlikely that she'd be hustled into the killing room the next week.

Beyond that, if the murders occurred in Canada, it would be the *Canadian* government that would try her for murder, unless a push was made for extradition or she was only arrested once she returned to the States... in which case if the US tried her for murder the Canadian government might request that she be returned to Canada for trial there.

There are a lot of potential obstacles notwithstanding method of execution.

Answer (score 0):

**Death by organ harvest.**

1. Outre and not done, and so without precedent that might contaminate your story.  But sensible enough and so good for a fiction.
2. Sentenced must choose this method among (many) others.  Those choosing this method might do so because they want to pay debt to society.
3. Less wasteful.
4. What happens to the people who get her regeneration-powered organs?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the forms of banned executions in the US are based on the horrific nature of failed executions.   In a world where super-human survival is more common, US law would likely adapt to make a death sentence as guaranteed as possible since botched executions are a typical consideration for what makes one method cruel vs another.

So, instead of more options, there would probably be one option, that is designed to account for all the ways super human survival might work.  So you might see something like sedation followed by bullet to the head followed by cremation followed by separating the ashes into multiple vessels or something like.

Comment: It's not drug resistance that requires three-drug lethal injections; the first drug is an anaesthetic to make the process painless, the second is a paralytic to prevent the subject from thrashing about while the third drug induces cardiac arrest.

Comment: Thanks,  answer updated.